# Store canvas image to mysql using path location

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, canvas

I'm trying to save my canvas image (generated by the user in the template) in my database. I've been through a lot of sources here, majority I've combined everything on it and got pretty much confused.

Steps that I'm trying to make:

1. Html form where provides different choices asked from the user **(done)**
2. Each time the user selects his/her choice, beside of it is the canvas that displays the image. **(done)**
3. A button that displays the summary of his choices and the canvas image generated through modal **(done)**
4. A button to Submit his order with the image in database using php and mysql **No error! But it doesn't store my image**

I don't need to download it, i just want it to directly store in my database once submitted

So where I'm stuck is in the **STEP 4** 
I'll give a summary choice on my codes: (it works fine in my file, just giving you the outcome idea)

```js
    
    /*This retrieves my data my JS w/c is same file with my HTML:  */
    $('#review').click(function () { 
    $('#shape').html($('input[name="shape_design"]:checked').val());
    $('#color').html($('input[name="color_design"]:checked').val());
    

//in this part, i am getting the image displayed in the canvas based on the user's choice
    var canvasSource = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var contextSource = canvasSource.getContext('2d');
    var canvasShow = document.getElementById('show_canvas');
    var contextShow = canvasShow.getContext('2d');
    var image = contextSource.getImageData(0, 0, canvasSource.width, canvasSource.height);
    contextShow.putImageData(image, 0, 0); });
     });
        


     $(function () { //this function converts the canvas to image, so it is now called as "Show Canvas" , it display well in my modal... not sure if its the right code
       $("#submitBtn").bind("click", function () {
       var base64 = $('#myCanvas')[0].toDataURL();
       $("#show_canvas").attr("src", base64);
       $("#show_canvas").show();
       });
      });

        

   //After reviewing it, this part will perform to store it in the database.. which is quite I'm confused
    $('#submitOrder').click(function(confirm){
      swal({ //sweetalert style
        title: "ORDER SENT", },
      function(submit){
        setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('#showchoices').submit();   }, 500); //"showchoices" is the name of the Html form, it will proceed to ordersent.php
        });
       });
```

For my php which I'm not sure what I'm doing.
**Ordersent.php**

```
   <? php
            $shape_design = $_POST['shape_design'];
            $color_design = $_POST['color_design'];
            $upload_dir = "upload/";  //what does this do?
            $myCanvas = $_POST['myCanvas']; //myCanvas is the name and id in my form
            $myCanvas = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $myCanvas);
            $myCanvas = str_replace(' ', '+', $myCanvas);
            $data = base64_decode($myCanvas);
            $file = $upload_dir."image_name.png";
            $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);

          $dbc = @mysql_connect('localhost' , 'root', '');
          @mysql_select_db('order_tbl', $dbc);
          $query1 = "INSERT INTO choices_tbl VALUES (NULL,'$shape_design','$color_design', '$myCanvas')";

            if(@mysql_query($query1,$dbc))
              {    Header("Location: /home.php");  }  
            else {  print 'error!! '.mysql_error().'';  }
?>
```

I tried following the instructions most of the tutorial, but it doesn't work on me.
I wanted to save it in my database using PATH , my my data type in my tables are

**order_tbl**
**designID INT(6) NOT NULL** ,
**shape_design VARCHAR(20)** ,
**color_design VARCHAR(20)** , 
**myCanvas VARCHAR(150)** ,

am I missing an attribute?
thanks for the help in advance! Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: Your syntax for insert is wrong.

INSERT INTO table_name ( 'shape_design','color_design' , 'myCanvas')
                       VALUES'
                       ( $cake_theme, $occassion_select,$myCanvas );

Comment: @NavjotSingh oh sorry, typo. thanks! But without the canvas using the same code, shape and color design can be easily stored in my database. I'm having trouble to insert the generated image